# How can I transform a column into date format?

Tags: sas

One of my date column doesn't read in date format, but I need to use the function `WEEKDAY()` on it.
How can I transform the data format of that column into date format?

**UPDATE:**
It is a csv file, following is one of the rows

> 01OCT2007,4.92,7.75

Comment: Can you tell how the column looks in the source data file? Is it a csv/txt file after all?

Comment: @psj This is a csv file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this (where foo.txt contains your data without column names)

```
data foo;
    infile "foo.txt" delimiter=',';
    informat a date.;
    format a date.;
    input a b c;
run;
```

?

psj

Comment: Thanks!! It works!! Would you mind telling me why I cant use PROC import to handle the date?

Comment: @Benjamin: you can. If I use instead PROC IMPORT OUT= WORK.FOO DATAFILE= "foo.csv"           DBMS=CSV REPLACE; GETNAMES=NO; DATAROW=1; RUN; I get the same result as above.

Comment: Hum.. My code should be something wrong, I cant work with this code.

Anyway Thanks!!